# Add option to choose the sites we want to apply the email subscriptions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, email

The new email subscription page is very good in UX but the only issue I found is it allow network wide subscription. It doesn't allow to choose only for one site.

[image]

In the above image, the +61 more points to network profile list of accounts section.

Then I tried whether setting on a particular site allow to subscribe only for that site. but negative.

[image]

So what can I do if I want to subscribe for inbox on Community milestones from Travel but not in Stack Overflow?

Please add the +61 more as a Dropdown check box which allow us to choose the list of sites the below settings will affect.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All information about what you are subscribed to is held at the network account level and we have no plans to start storing this per site. Doing so hugely complicates synchronization between sites and makes auditing and tracking of unsubscribes far more complex.

It's unlikely that this will change, sorry.

Comment: expecting a [tag:status-completed] in 6-8 weeks :)

Comment: @SagarV Hope you are misread, the status change is `status-declined` not `status-planned`

Comment: yeah. that's why I said a [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/228134)